# Unable to grab text from form_input

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to obtain items that are within my view input boxes.
    I am using:

```
$email = $this->input->post('email', true);
```

In order to obtain the what is within the input box. But it is not obtaining anything.

The function is run with:

```
<?php $function = array('auth/start', $price);?>

<form action="<?php echo base_url($function);?>"method="post">
<script
src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
data-key="pk_test_xZrfWwuBmwBzUBynB96OgZhU"
data-amount="" 
data-name="Turbine Engine"
data-description="Individual Membership"
data-image="/128x128.png">
</script>
</form>
```

I have the following:

Controller:

```
function start()
           {
                $username = 'a';
                $price = '100';
                $password = 'password';
                $email = $this->input->post('email');

                $end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 years'));

                $additional_data = array(
            'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
                            'middle_initial' => $this->input->post('middle_initial'),
            'last_name'  => $this->input->post('last_name'),
            'company'    => $this->input->post('company'),
            'phone'      => $this->input->post('phone'),
                        'biography'      => $this->input->post('biography'),
                        'address'      => $this->input->post('address'),
                        'city'      => $this->input->post('city'),
                        'state'      => $this->input->post('state'),
                        'zip'      => $this->input->post('zip'),
                        'position'      => $this->input->post('position'),
                        'country'      => $this->input->post('country'),
                        'website'      => $this->input->post('website'),
                            'listing'               => 'N',
                            'type'                  => 'I',
                            'registration_end' => $end,
        );


               //load payment library
               $this->load->library( 'stripe' );


               // Get the credit card details submitted by the form
               $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];



               // Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
                try {


                    //attempt to charge user
                    $this->stripe->charge_card( intval($price), $token, "Individual Membership" );
                    } 
                    catch(Stripe_CardError $e) 
                    {
                      // The card has been declined
                    }


        //If passed then add a new user
                    //add the user
                    $this->ion_auth->register($username, $password, $email, $additional_data);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Payment Successful');

                  //TEST
                  //load parameters
                  $type = 'new account';
                  $date = date('Y-m-d');
                  date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Melbourne');
                  $time = date('h:i:s a', time());
                  //load the controller for adding activity
                  $this->load->library('../controllers/activity');
                  $this->activity->insert($email, $type, $date, $time);

                    //send to login
                    //$this->showView('login');
        redirect("auth", 'refresh');

     }
```

View:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">

        <!--Put Labels in order-->
        <style>
            label 
            {
         display: inline-block;
     width: 120px;
    }
    </style>

 <h4>Individual Payment Page</h4>

 <b>Make sure your email is correct</b>

 <hr>


 <p>
        <?php echo form_label("Email:");?> <br />
        <?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'email', 'name'=>'email','value'=>$email,'size'=>'30',
 'readonly'=>'true'));?>
  </p>

<!-- Make Hidden Labels to Pass the username and password-->
   <p>
        <?php echo form_input('username',$username);?>
        <?php echo form_input('password',$password);?>
        <?php echo form_input('first_name', $first_name);?>
        <?php echo form_input('middle_initial',$middle_initial);?>
        <?php echo form_input('last_name', $last_name);?>
        <?php echo form_input('company', $company);?>
        <?php echo form_input('phone', $phone);?>
        <?php echo form_input('biography',$biography);?>
        <?php echo form_input('address', $address);?>
        <?php echo form_input('city', $city);?>
        <?php echo form_input('state', $state);?>
        <?php echo form_input('zip', $zip);?>
       <?php echo form_input('position', $position);?>
       <?php echo form_input('country', $country);?>
       <?php echo form_input('website', $website);?>
  </p>
  <br>


  <p>
      <b>Click Below for Payment</b> <br>
  </p>

  <p><h4>1.) Regular Individual </h4><br>
  <?php echo form_label("Price:");?> <br />
        <?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'price','value'=>$price,'size'=>'30',
 'readonly'=>'true'));?>
  </p>


  <?php $function = array('auth/start', $price);?>

  <form action="<?php echo base_url($function);?>"method="post">
  <script
  src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
  data-key="pk_test_xZrfWwuBmwBzUBynB96OgZhU"
  data-amount="" 
  data-name="Turbine Engine"
  data-description="Individual Membership"
  data-image="/128x128.png">
  </script>
  </form>

  <p><h4>2.) Regular Individual with Listing Enabled</h4><br>
  <?php echo form_label("Price:");?> <br />
        <?php echo     form_input(array('name'=>'price_listing','value'=>$total,'size'=>'30',
 'readonly'=>'true'));?>
  </p>
 <?php $function2 = array('auth/start_listing', $username, $password, $email, $first_name, $middle_initial, $last_name, $company, $phone, urldecode($address), $city, $state, $zip, urldecode($biography), $position, urldecode($country), urldecode($website), $total);?>

<form action="<?php echo base_url($function2);?>"method="post">
<script
src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
data-key="pk_test_xZrfWwuBmwBzUBynB96OgZhU"
data-amount="" 
data-name="Turbine Engine"
data-description="Individual Membership"
data-image="/128x128.png">
 </script>
</form>


    </div>
</div>
</div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Thank you. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view you have this:

```
//...
<?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'email', name'=>'email','value'=>$email,'size'=>'30', 'readonly'=>'true'));?>
//...
<form action="<?php echo base_url($function);?>"method="post">
    // ...
</form>
```

But you didn't open the form before this input, so your inputs are not submitting, so open the form first like this:

```
echo form_open('url here');
    echo form_input(array('id' => 'email', 'name'=>'email','value'=>$email,'size'=>'30', 'readonly'=>'true'));
    //other inputs...
form_close();
```

The `form_open` opens/creates the opening form tag and `form_close` creates the closing form tag. You can also use `<form>` and `</form>` so put all your inputs inside the form before:

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button" ...></script>
```

Read more about [Form Helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is no any form_open() and form_close() in you input form. Please update your code this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

in order to post your text field  you need to enclose it in a form tag

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="" />
<form action="someurl" method="post">
</form>
```

in this situation nothing will get posted to the server 
if you need to post the text field you will need move it inside the form tags

```
<form action="someurl" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="email" value="" />
</form>
```

or

```
form_open('someurl');
   <?php echo form_label("Email:");?> <br />
   <?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'email', name'=>'email','value'=>$email,'size'=>'30', 'readonly'=>'true'));?>
form_close();
```

make sure all the text filed are wraped inside a form